# How to evaluate function only once in ternary operators?

Tags: php, performance, memory, ternary-operator

I wonder if I can make a single-line ternary operator that checks the value returned by a function, and uses it?

Let's check this example (PHP) code:

```
return get_db_row($sql_parameters) ? get_db_row($sql_parameters) : get_empty_row();
```

my purpose is to return `get_db_row()` , but if it is empty, then return an empty row.

But, **I think**, this line will call `get_db_row()` *twice*. Is it right ?

I want to call it once. One solution could be storing the return value in a variable like this:

```
$row = get_db_row($sql_parameters);
return $row ? $row : get_empty_row();
```

But can I do this in one line?

Something like :

```
return ($row = get_db_row()) ? $row : get_empty_row();
```

is it possible ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Your last example should work fine. You're assigning the result of get_db_row() to the $row variable and evaluating it at the same time. Have you tried it? That's the best way to see if it works or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it correct. The following line will only call the function once:

```
return ($row = get_db_row()) ? $row : get_empty_row();
```

Some code to prove this:

```
$counter = 0;
function test() {
    global $counter;
    $counter++;
    return true;
}

$var = ($ret = test()) ? $ret : 'bar';
echo sprintf("#1 called the function %d times\n", $counter);

$counter = 0;
$var = ($ret = test()) ? test() : 'bar';
echo sprintf("#2 called the function %d times", $counter);
```

Outputs:

```
#1 called the function 1 times
#2 called the function 2 times
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/95127)

Answer (score 0):

```
return get_db_row($sql_parameters) ?: get_empty_row();
```

If you're running an earlier version of PHP that doesn't support this...

```
return ($x = get_db_row($sql_parameters)) ? $x : get_empty_row();
```

Should work just fine.